# How do you position a html block (<ul>) directly under a <input> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="pgContent">
            <div id="studyOverlay">
                <div id="studyContainer">
                    <div id="studyTest">
                        <div id="studyTestContainer">
                            <input class="dropInput">
                            <ul class="inputDrop">
                            <!--some <li>s-->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to use jQuery to position the `<ul>` directly underneath the `<input>`. This HTML shows only one `input` and `ul`, but there can be multiple with the same classes.

I tried this jQuery:

```
$('.dropInput').live('click', function() {
var offset = $(this).offset();
var height = $(this).height();
var width = $(this).width();
var top = offset.top + height + "px";
var right = offset.left + width + "px";

$(this).next().show();

$(this).next().css( {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'right': right,
    'top': top
});
});
```

but it positions it very strangely. My guess is that there is something with the offset and there being so many divs. Is there any way to fix this?

Or if you know a CSS way that would be even better!

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery as opposed to pure CSS?

Comment: Why not set display of input to block?  $(".dropInput").css("display","block");

Comment: @Mark I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @chromedude, see my update below

Comment: @chromedude, wouldn't it be easier to use a select box?

Comment: @Neal in some ways, but this looks far better and is more suited to the scenario

Comment: @chromedude, ok, i guess im just not sure of the senario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seemed to be able to do it with just css here:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AfJUG/

Sample css:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
}


#studyTestContainer {
    background: red;
}
```

That seems to do it, unless I am misunderstanding the issue at hand.

---

**UPDATE**:

JS:

```
$('.dropInput').focus(function(){
    $(this).next('.inputDrop').slideDown();
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).next('.inputDrop').slideUp();
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
}


#studyTestContainer {
    background: red;
}

.inputDrop {
    display: none;
}

.dropInput {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AfJUG/6/

---

New Fiddle based on comments below: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AfJUG/7/

---

And another: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AfJUG/9/

Comment: it needs to be absolutely positioned because it is overlaid ontop of other content

Comment: @chromedude, what do you mean?

Comment: there is text directly below the input and I want the <ul> to be a dropdown.

Comment: @Neal I just updated it with what I am talking about. The text is below the dropdown without absolute positioning and I want it to be underneath the dropdown (not able to be seen)

Comment: @Neal ok, but I need it to slide down over top of the bottom input, not move the bottom input down.

Comment: @chromedude, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AfJUG/7/ and see the changes i made to the css

Comment: @Neal, actually what I really need is this: http://jsfiddle.net/AfJUG/8/, I need the inputs to be inline-block . Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSGJN/)):

```css
.dropInput{}
.inputDrop{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<div id="pgContent">
  <div id="studyOverlay">
    <div id="studyContainer">
      <div id="studyTest">
        <div id="studyTestContainer">
          <input class="dropInput">
          <ul class="inputDrop">
            <!--some <li>s-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```